# Using getElementByClassName to build an object array

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `getElementsByClassName` to get a collection of `tr`.

I want to now iterate through the collection and get the value of a textbox in the `tr`.

I cannot use `JQuery` to do this or any other framework.

How can this be done?

```
var dom = document.getElementsByClassName('Row');
var arr = [];
var len = dom.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   // foo = look up value of a text box in this row 
   // bar = look up value of a text box in this row 
   var obj = {
   quantity: foo,
   price: bar
   };
 arr.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: Link above is important to note, as getElementsByClassName is only from IE9 and onwards

Comment: Thanks, I am not actually using `getElementsByClassName` but put it in to simplify the example. I am using a `YUI` method that returns exactly the same thing @MackieeE @mu is too short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's `getElementsByClassName`, with an 's' -- it can get more than one element, so its name is a plural.

Secondly, `getElementsByClassName` is not a function on it's own, it's a method on a DOM object.

If you want to get all elements in the document that match a given class name, you have to call `document.getElementsByClassName()`, not just `getElementsByClassName()` on its own.

So you need to do this:

```
var dom = document.getElementsByClassName('Row');
```

The elements within the `dom` object you get back from this also has the same methods available as the root `document` object, you can can call `dom[i].getElementsByClassName()`, etc.

For example, in order to get all the `textarea` elements within it, you could do `dom[i].getElementsBtTagName('textarea')`.

That should help get you going.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct & my mistake. How can I now look up a textbox in a `tr` when I iterate through the colllection @Spudley

Comment: @ojhawkins - I've added a bit more to the answer, to try to help a bit more.

Comment: Should I be able to use `dom[i].getElementById('foo')`? @Spudley

Comment: yep, that would work too; any of the dom methods should work. (although specifically `getElementById()` would be less useful, since an ID is supposed to be unique on a page so it shouldn't be necessary to call by ID from here as the result would be the same as calling from `document`)